# Git log commends date format java

Tags: java, git

I have problem with format of date for commends --after --before.
git

```
"git -C " + RepositoryConstants.root + reponame + " log --pretty=format:\"%h|%an|%ad|%s\" --after='" + dateFrom___ + "' --before='" + dateTo___ + "' --date=iso");
```

This is what is set in my program. and it don't work. But when i copy it to console its fine, same as when i have dates in format '2016-02-05' but not with hours and minutes.

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(string from upstair);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                        Commit commit = new Commit();
                        System.out.println(">>> " + line);
                        String split[] = line.split("\\|");
                         ...
                        }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        p.waitFor();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    return stuff;


private DateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm");
    String dateFrom___ = "'" + outputFormatter.format(dateFrom__) + "'";
    String dateTo___ = "'" + outputFormatter.format(dateTo__) + "'";
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"git", " -C ", RepositoryConstants.REPOSITORY_ROOT + repo, " log"," --pretty=format:\"%h|%an|%ad|%s\"", " --after=", dateFrom___,  " --before=", dateTo___, " --date=iso"});
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using it in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java uses a [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) for parsing the command to arguments in the [exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) call. This class doesn't respect the quotes as the shell does.

You should manually split the string, and pass a array to the method:

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"-C","C:\test\repo","log","--pretty=format:%h|%an|%ad|%s", "--after=2016-02-05 15:24:00 +0100", "--before=2016-02-24 10:32:00 +0100" "--date=iso"});
```

Comment: Is there posiblity that there are problem with space between date hours and days? Couse i use this exec, and still don't get result, but String[] is working when i copy it to console.

Comment: I see you edited `git` to the start of the command in a later edit to the post, did you add that to the command here too when you tried it?

Comment: I added how it looks right now at bottom of post. Still not working.

Comment: When splitting, you should manually remove the spaces, because else those spaces will be passed to the program, causing problems there.    `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"git", "-C", RepositoryConstants.REPOSITORY_ROOT + repo, "log","--pretty=format:%h|%an|%ad|%s", "--after=" + dateFrom___,  "--before=" + dateTo___, "--date=iso"});`